# loop command in a linux file with multiple columns in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file.txt as below with "n" number of columns. I need to run command in loop, that needs to have first column value and the second column value. Upon complete, execute the command to have first column value and the third and it continues for all the columns in a row.

Example:

```
vcloud <ktrcigmv> diskcommand <persistent-disk-1>
vcloud <ktrcigmv> diskcommand <persistent-disk-2>
vlcoud <ktrcsnu1> diskcommand <persistent-disk-1>
vlcoud <ktrcsnu1> diskcommand <persistent-disk-4>
vlcoud <ktrcsnu1> diskcommand <persistent-disk-6>
```

input(?):

```
ktrcigmv       persistent-disk-1 persistent-disk-2
ktrcsnu1       persistent-disk-1 persistent-disk-4 persistent-disk-6
ktrsapahn       vol-71412041887658--dev-sdd-cc04ce65
ktrai2y5h       persistent-disk-1
ktrcibiy       persistent-disk-1
ktrcigf2       persistent-disk-1
ktrcisxh       persistent-disk-1
ktrsapmam       vol-345052022286--dev-sdb-b5d5bdfd vol-345052022286--dev-sdf-9c91de4d
ktrcie8x       persistent-disk-1
ktrcio3s       persistent-disk-1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: I added the line `input:` to the bottom part. Now I have two quite contrary solutions: one collecting, one scattering.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is *wanted*:

```
vcloud ktrcigmv
diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcigmv
diskcommand persistent-disk-2
vcloud ktrcsnu1
diskcommand persistent-disk-1
```

or with TAB after the "vcloud ..." and the *bottom* part of OP as input:

```
vcloud ktrcigmv diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcigmv diskcommand persistent-disk-2
vcloud ktrcsnu1 diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcsnu1 diskcommand persistent-disk-4
vcloud ktrcsnu1 diskcommand persistent-disk-6
vcloud ktrsapahn        diskcommand vol-71412041887658--dev-sdd-cc04ce65
vcloud ktrai2y5h        diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcibiy diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcigf2 diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcisxh diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrsapmam        diskcommand vol-345052022286--dev-sdb-b5d5bdfd
vcloud ktrsapmam        diskcommand vol-345052022286--dev-sdf-9c91de4d
vcloud ktrcie8x diskcommand persistent-disk-1
vcloud ktrcio3s diskcommand persistent-disk-1
```

This looks like the *top* part of OP, minus the "<".

This is done by e.g.:

```
while (<>) {
    ($v, @ds) = split;
    for $d (@ds) { 
        print "vcloud $v\t";
        print "diskcommand $d\n";
    }
}
```

And then replace "print" with "system".

The parens around `($v, @ds)` are needed - here is where first item and the rest are separated.

---

My original interpretation (the other way round. input=output):

```
while (<>) {
    @F = split;
    $tbl{$F[1]} .= $F[3];
}
for $k (keys %tbl) {
    print "$k $tbl{$k}", "\n";
}
```

this prints:

```
]# perl kt.pl ktxt 
<ktrcigmv> <persistent-disk-1><persistent-disk-2>
<ktrcsnu1> <persistent-disk-1><persistent-disk-4><persistent-disk-6>
```

---

I'd be glad to explain a bit.

With "autosplit" `perl -a ...` option you can condense it to:

```
$tbl{$F[1]} .= "$F[3] ";
END {
for $k (keys %tbl) { print "$k:   $tbl{$k}", "\n" }
}
```

this prints now, with some formatting added:

```
]# perl -a kt.pl ktxt 
<ktrcsnu1>:   <persistent-disk-1> <persistent-disk-4> <persistent-disk-6> 
<ktrcigmv>:   <persistent-disk-1> <persistent-disk-2>
```

With `perl -a` or `perl -F` the `@F` array is "magic", that is why I used it also in my first example. It stands for "Fields". `$F[0]` is the first field.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`'s `awk` mode:

```
<file.txt perl -lae '
   system "vcloud", $F[0], "diskcommand", $_ for @F[1..$#F]'
```

Would run `vcloud field-1 diskcommand field-n` for each *field-2* .. *field-last* (note that array indices start at 0, not 1 in `perl`, hence the `1..$#F`) on each line.

The field delimiter is any sequence of ASCII whitespace (space, tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return), leading and trailing whitespace on each line is ignored.